# Theme.AppCompat not found using v7-appcompat APKLIB

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library, android-appcompat, apklib

I've added the v4 and v7-appcompat support dependecies into my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>android.support</groupId>
     <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
     <version>18</version>
     <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
</dependency>
```

And now I want to add the AppCompat style to my activities, but it's not found. It seems the AppCompat resources have not been loaded from the APKLIB.

Does anyone know why that's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: You can chek if AppCompat resources really present in apklib. Just find this apklib in your local maven repository and open it as zip archive